# 頭がいい人 versus 頭が切れる人

Tags: meaning

I could not find the explanation of my following question in English. What are the main differences between 頭がいい人 and 頭が切れる人? It is still  hard for me to understand the Japanese version given in [this link (click)](https://careerpark.jp/5094?page=2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to that site:

頭がいい人

- Born smart
- Academic / scholastic definition of smart
- Good at studying and doing things they are told
- Highly productive

頭が切れる人

- Smartness acquired through practice and experience
- "Street smart"
- Good at learning things there is no manual / instructions for by exploration
- Not the most productive worker, but has unexpected insights

Bear in mind that is just one net article's opinion, and seems a little biased towards appealing the 頭が切れる人 type, but there's still some valuable distinctions there.